# How many BFS orderings are there?

Tags: algorithm, graph, complexity-theory, graph-algorithm, space-complexity

Given a graph *G(V,E)* and a source vertex *s*, how many BFS orderings are there and how would an algorithm look like to find them all?

### Examples

A graph with only one vertex *A* has exactly one BFS ordering for *s=A*, namely [*A*].

A graph with two connected vertices *A* and *B* has one BFS ordering for *s=A*, namely [*A*,*B*]

A graph with tree vertices *A*,*B* and *C* all connected to each other has two BFS orderings for *s=A*, namely [*A*,*B*,*C*] and [*A*,*C*,*B*]

Answer (score 1):

You need a BFS algorithm augmented to backtrack and find all valid orderings.  You'll need to do the search in passes, one pass for each layer (shortest distance from start node).

```
"done" <- [start node]
"open" <- [all other nodes]
"pending" <- empty list

while "open" is not empty
    for each node in "done",
        for each adjacent node
            if the node is not in "done",
                add it to "pending".
    for each node in "pending"
        add node to "done", recording the added step in a solution
        recur, using new path as set of start nodes, other nodes as "pending"
            BUT ... if no nodes are pending, record this path as a solution.
```

Is that enough of an outline to get you moving?

Note that you can shorten this greatly with dynamic programming: memoize sub-solutions for a given `path` set and latest node.  For a large graph, this allows you to avoid duplicating continuations from, say, ABCD and ACBD.  These two cases will have the same continuation.

Comment: If dN is the number of nodes at a distance N from s, isn't the total number of DFS orderings simply d1! + d2! + d3! + ... +dN! ?

Comment: That may work to find the quantity, but it doesn't find the orderings.

Comment: The question seems to be to simply count them, not enumerate them. In the ABC example, there are two nodes at distance 1, so 2! = 2. You don't have to know that the two orderings are ABC and ACB to count them. (Or maybe I'm interpreting the question wrong?)

Comment: "... how would an algorithm look like to find them all?" is where I derive the need to find all the paths.

Comment: Oh, indeed; there seem to be two questions. (Btw, I meant d1! * d2! * ... not d1! + d2! + ...)

Comment: Seems like you could just find one, marking the level boundaries, and then iterate over the permutations

Comment: @rici: I'm not clear on what you mean.  Why not work through the idea and post another answer?

Comment: Because it is too complicated to type without a real keyboard and I probably won't be in front of one until the weekend. But the idea is similar to m69's counting algo: any kevel can be permuted independently of any other level.

Answer (score 0):

I think if we draw a bfs tree we can get suppose
Level is from 0 to n and N(level no) gives the number of nodes in that level 
Then 
for(i=0;i

Answer (score 0):

For finite graphs, counting BFS orderings is equivalent to count DFS pre or post orderings which is equivalent to counting topological sorts.  This is in the sharp #P complete complexity class and considered to be a problem harder than NP.